# How to add or delete objects from React - Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, reactjs, react-rails

I have a Rails app with `react-rails` gem.

This is my controller:

```
class WebsitesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @websites = Website.all
  end
end
```

This is my view:

```
<%= react_component('WebsiteList', websites: @websites) %>
```

This is my React component wit:

```
class WebsiteList extends React.Component {

  render () {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <AddWebsite/>
        <WebsiteItem websites={this.props.websites}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

WebsiteList.propTypes = {
  websites: React.PropTypes.node
};
```

In WebsiteItem it's just mapping the array and showing each object.

AddWebsite Component with ajax to get data on the server:

```
class AddWebsite extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      formValue: "http://www."
    }
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({formValue: e.target.value});
  }

  submitForm() {
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "/websites",
      data: { website: {name: "New Web", url: this.state.formValue} }
    })
      .done(function() {
        console.log("done")
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input value={this.state.formValue} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} name="url"/>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.submitForm.bind(this)} className="btn">Add Web</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

When someone adds (or delete) a link and ajax is success, I'd like to update the React component as well. Instead of this.props.websites & propTypes - how I could do it for state? Do I need to get the it from ajax or can I use the `<%=react_component ... %>` in erb?

What is the best way to solve it and create basically a single page app?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand but can you not use React's setState in the done callback to change the state of the component?

Comment: I tried to do it - like now I have "this.props.websites" that I got from PropTypes websites: React.PropTypes.node. I tried to do this.state = {websites: ...} but didn't figure out what should be instead the three dots.

Comment: Oh gotcha will post an answer in a bit.

Comment: I actually managed it by passing an argument in constructor but now I am thinking how to add website and update the this.state.websites

Comment: Can you share the source code so that I'm on the same page?

Comment: Sure :) sorry it's quite confusing the question now. This is the source code: https://github.com/Dudisek/react-rails/tree/master/app/assets/javascripts/components there is a dashboard and two components with ajax requests - one add_website and second delete_website. It's going to the server but I'd like to update also the this.state.websites (receiving new data from the server in json)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123612/discussion-between-marek-suscak-and-dudis).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so what you really want is to have a callback in the `AddWebsite` component passed from the `Dashboard` where you hold the app state. Please note that the `this.state` is component bound which means you can not access state of another component. You can pass the state of one component as a property to another though and that's what we're going to use.

```
// dashboard.es6.jsx
class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      websites: this.props.websites
    }

    // Don't forget to bind to self
    this.handleWebsiteAdd = this.handleWebsiteAdd.bind(this)
  }

  handleWebsiteAdd(newWebsite) {
    const websites = this.state.websites.concat([newWebsite]);

    this.setState({websites});       
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <AddWebsite onAdd={this.handleWebsiteAdd}/>
        <WebsiteList websites={this.state.websites}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// add_website.es6.jsx
class AddWebsite extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      formValue: "http://www."
    }
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({formValue: e.target.value});
  }

  submitForm() {
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "/websites",
      data: { website: {name: "New Web", url: this.state.formValue} }
    })
      .done(function(data) {
        // NOTE: Make sure that your API endpoint returns new website object
        // Also if your response is structured differently you may need to extract it 
        // and instead of passing data directly, pass one of its properties.
        this.props.onAdd(data)
        Materialize.toast('We added your website', 4000)
      }.bind(this))
      .fail(function() {
        Materialize.toast('Not a responsive URL', 4000)
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="card">
        <div className="input-field" id="url-form">
          <h5>Add new website</h5>
          <form>
            <input id="url-input" value={this.state.formValue} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} type="text" name="url"/>
            <button type="button" onClick={this.submitForm.bind(this)} className="btn">Add Web</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

AddWebsite.propTypes = {
  onAdd: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

Please note this is just one of the many possible solutions.